# Как с помощью javascript/jquery получить ID элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

На странице есть

```
<td id="#X"><input id="status" name="status"></td>
```

Мне нужно AJAXом обновить содержимое БД в соответствии с написанным в поле.
Строчка параметров выглядит так:

```
data: 'action=setStatus&status=' + t.value + '&id=' + document.getElementById("...ID ?").value,
```

Как мне вместо "document.getElementById("...ID ?").value" получить тот ID, который у TD?

Comment: Обычно не рекомендуется использовать спецсимволы в id элементов.  Поэтому пишите лучше <td id="x">. Иначе, например, в CSS вам придется писать ##x { свойства }, что является ошибкой синтаксиса.

Comment: нет, я не использую #X, я пишу в качестве ID обычное число, это я написала чтобы обозначить порядковый номер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить родителя - .parentNode. Получить id - .id

```
var inp = document.getElementById('status');
var td = inp.parentNode;
var ID_of_TD = td.id;
console.log(ID_of_TD); // "x"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b12evuph/

Comment: Если ответ вас удовлетворил, нажмите галочку "Ответ" рядом с рейтингом ответа.